# AJAX: GET Request After Setting innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, ajax, logic, innerhtml

Using the W3School example (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_ajax_intro.asp):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo">
<h1>The XMLHttpRequest Object</h1>
<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>
</div>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
      this.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain why the GET action occurs after the innerHTML is set?

Logically, I'm used to languages which progress from top to bottom, working on each line of code step by step.

When I read this for the first time, I assume that the innerHTML for the **demo** element will be blank, and that there's no action which re-sets the innerHTML to the results from *ajax_info.txt* following the server request. Thinking of this in back-end languages, had the innerHTML been a variable, it would have to be updated, and the last statement might appear like this:

```
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
```

Example in pseudocode using variables:

1. var x = '' or NULL;
2. var y = GET text from file on the server;
3. var x = y;

Comment: it's because you're assigning to `onreadystatechange` a function that will be executed in later point in the future when the response arrives, however  the interpreter proceeds to execute remaining code. read about asynchronous JS

Comment: Perfect. I'll take a look. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Maximus the interpreter does 'execute' the code as is, it just so happens the code is a function declaration.

Comment: @pvg, yeah, I know :). And it's actually function expression

Comment: @Maximus there's no getting away from js people and their crazy moon terminology! Anyway, the (inartfully stated) point was that the posters premise is wrong even for simple cases they likely already know about: writing a function doesn't actually invoke it so even without async, things don't run in lexical order.

Comment: @pvg, yeah, that's a valid point. That's may be what OP doesn't understand as well

Answer (score 0):

`onreadystatechange` is a listener, it is not executed straight away, but listens to the XHR request for that event.

When the event is triggered, for example when the response comes back from the server, then the code will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also exchange the order of `xhttp.onreadystatechange` and `xhttp.open()`.

The request will only be sent to the server **after** excuting `xhttp.send()`.

And in `xhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){}` you can find

`if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
// dom excution
}`

which means dom excution after  `xhttp.send()` sending the request to the server and the `readyState==4 &&status==200`.

Answer (score -1):

In javascript there is no guarantee that every code will be execute one after another. If some line takes time , then the second line start excution. So here if some execution precedence is required then need to apply the callbacks.For the case of Ajax follow the synch or async way.